# Restangular get in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using get function of Restangular. And in return i get an object which have customers and some other functions of restangular but these functions of restangular are not associated to list of customer.

Why? Is there any other way?

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: The thing is when i used getList() it simply return array as response and all the records(object) contain restangular functions like save, patch, plain, post etc.
But now i want some other information too like records_count, next_cursor, prev_cursor. So for this i used get('', params = {}) which return response { records: [..], save(), plain(), patch().. }
I am asking in records array, record object doesnt have the restangular functions like save(), plain(), patch() etc.

So is there any way to add restangular function to each record.

Comment: So, you would like to add some custom function to the collection of customers?

Comment: No i want the restangular functions(save, delete) on each records. And those are not coming over that. Restangular function are only appearing at the root of response.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to describe in a better way what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use .plain() for this.

```
Restangular.one('accounts', 1234)
    .then(function (account) {
        account.plain(); // object whitout the restangular methods
    });
```